# How to modify html response using Vite proxy configuration

Tags: node.js, proxy, vite

I have a following Vite configuration:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

const zlib = require("zlib");

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    server: {
      proxy: {
        "/start": {
          target: "https://someremoteurl.com",
          secure: false,
          changeOrigin: true,
          configure: (proxy) => {
            proxy.on("proxyRes", (proxyRes, req, res) => {
              const chunks = [];
              
              proxyRes.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
              proxyRes.on("end", () => {
                const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                const encoding = proxyRes.headers["content-encoding"];
                if (encoding === "gzip" || encoding === "deflate") {
                  zlib.unzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
                    if (!err) {
                      let remoteBody = buffer.toString();
                      const modifiedBody = remoteBody.replace() // do some string manipulation on remoteBody
                      res.write(modifiedBody);
                      res.end();
                    } else {
                      console.error(err);
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            });
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
});
```

Everything works as expected modifiedBody is of needed shape.

However the server doesn't return the modified response, it retuns the initial html that the "https://someremoteurl.com" url served.

With the following code the response is "correctly" changed:

```js
              proxyRes.on("end", () => {
                res.end('<h1>Some Test HTML</h1>')
              });
```

But this wouldnt work for me, as i need to read the response first, unzip it, modify it and only then send back.

To me it looks like the proxied response is streamed, but dev server doesn't wait for the response to first finish streaming, running transformations and only then serving the desired document.

Any idea how can i achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

As Vite uses the [http-node-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) lib under the hood i had to look fo the answer in their documentation. I found that `selfHandleResponse` option needs to be true in order to serve your modified response.

Setting that option solved my question.